# What types of tests are performed on IoT Devices and what are the best approaches to be taken?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, iot

This question is related to Testing and gives some tips about IOT Testing

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad and gives no information about the background about the Thing, nor it's functionality.  Do you want to test it's functionality, communications or security?  What have you done already?

Answer (score 0):

Internet of Things (IoT) has penetrated almost all industries. With the rise of technology and market demands, organizations are planning to build IoT products to extend their connected ecosystems. To deal with the challenges like complexity, huge volume, architecture, and variety of data, organizations need to come up with unique IoT Testing (Quality Assurance) strategies to ensure the reliability of their products and devices.

Major Types of IoT Testing: With the evolution of technology, a whole new level of complexity has been introduced into testing IoT devices. A tester ought to verify all the tools and metrics to confirm the reliability of the application once it interacts or communicates with hardware over a defined network.

Security Testing: Security testing includes the testing of information security, confidentiality, and desirableness of the system for continuous quality within the IoT environment. Security Testing also ensures that steps are being taken to remain stable, ensuring safety and privacy are correct due to delicate information stored in connected devices.

Compatibility Testing: It is a scope of how varied devices interact with the digital environment. There are many validation considerations such as hardware compatibility, encoding checks & security standards for the device layer to the network layer that are dead in this type of testing. Hence, addressing the compatibility issues that arise out of the connected devices.

Performance Testing: The main objective of this kind of testing is to standardize the association with the item and also the code with which it interacts. Performance testing validates the hardware and software components of a device with many test cases. It ensures that an application can handle the projected increase in user traffic data volume, transaction counts frequency, etc.

User-Experience Testing: User experience testing defines how a particular application or system works across various interfaces and channels. Based on the knowledge gathered from numerous use cases, a tester can ensure the user-experience, front-end, and back-end functionalities. This will ensure pleasant user experience and address the challenges that arise due to usability issues.

Exploratory Testing: The accomplishment of any application is determined by its users, this is to each IoT application that meets all requirements. Therefore, it's essential to perform exploratory testing to ensure how the application works while interacting with real-time users and address real-time complexities.